# Nginx HTTPS config issue for non-wws

Tags: nginx, ssl, ruby-on-rails

I need to configure nginx for one of my rails application to route some pages through SSL but facing problem with configuration.

I've a SSL certificate where common name is **example.com** and my site is routing to **example.com** from www.example.com

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
  upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    #return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /certificate path;
    ssl_certificate_key  /key path;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    ssl_certificate      /certificate path;
    ssl_certificate_key  /key path;

    root /public directory;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    location @unicorn {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50M;
  }
```

I've tried different configuration as well but nothing work. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for that.

Comment: `my site is routing to example.com from www.example.com` - what does this mean, and in what way is it a problem/error?

Comment: @AD7six what i meant is - using non-www domain, redirecting from www to non-www which you'll see into the first "server" block. I am getting following error message - "This webpage is not available"

Comment: That probably means there is no dns entry for `example.com`, and has nothing to do with ssl or nginx. Though, your comment is as clear as the description in the question :P.

Comment: @morshed you have weird second server block. It redirects to itself.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I think so as well, can you please give me an idea what it should be.

Comment: As I could see now, you site works only on port 80, so no https. What exact URL you want you site to work on? `http` or `https`? With or without `www.`?

Comment: Missed to add HTTPS listener with load balancer. After configuring it's showing "404 Not Found" error. @AlexeyTen To answering your question - I want non-www(without www.) and keep https for some specific urls such as signup, checkout and all other route through http protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been resolved by doing modifications below, answering this as it might help someone else:

- Removed `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` from `default_server` block.
- Removed URL overwriting from SSL server block.
- Added `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_ciphers` to SSL server block

The configuration look like below after modification:

```
upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /example.com/current/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    ......
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols    TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    ......
}
```